# What's the meaning of "$\{α_1, \ldots , α_n\}$ is a basis of characteristic vectors for $T$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Here is a question I encountered in my homework.

> Let V be an n-dimensional vector space, and let T be a linear operator
> on V. Suppose that T is diagonalizable.
>
> If T has n distinct characteristic values, and if **{$\alpha_{1}$,
> ..., $\alpha_{n}$} is a basis of characteristic vectors for T**, show
> that $\alpha$ = $\alpha_{1}$ + ... + $\alpha_{n}$ is a cyclic vector
> for T.

I want to ask what's the meaning of "**{$\alpha_{1}$, ..., $\alpha_{n}$} is a basis of characteristic vectors for T**" ? Does it means {$\alpha_{1}$, ..., $\alpha_{n}$} are characteristic vectors?

Comment: Welcome to Maths  SX! I suppose, in relation to the context, it means ‘a basis of eigenvectors’.

Comment: An attempt in translation from German to English (by Halmos, I believe) that no one else adopted.  *Eigenwert* -> characteristic value; *Eigenvektor* -> characteristic vector.  Nowadays we just keep the German *Eigen* in there and say *eigenvector, eigenvalue, eigenfunction* and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that $\alpha$ is a characteristic vector (AKA eigenvector or proper vector) if there is a scalar (i.e. a number as opposed to a vector) $\lambda$ for which $T(\alpha) = \lambda \alpha$. The number $\lambda$ is called the "characteristic value" associated with the characteristic vector $\alpha$.

The phrase "$\{\alpha_{1},\dots , \alpha_{n}\}$ is a basis of characteristic vectors for $T$" means that $\{\alpha_{1},\dots , \alpha_{n}\}$ is a basis and that each vector $\alpha_i$ is a characteristic vector.

This is fairly standard English usage. Another example of such a phrase is "the object on the table is a wheel of cheese," which means that the object on the table is a wheel, and the material that comprises the wheel is cheese.

Comment: I think they want a definition of characteristic vector.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I concluded that this was probably not the case because they are apparently comfortable with the phrase "characteristic value". Can't hurt to add it in though.

Comment: Can't hurt to ask the OP 

Comment: @Chickenmancer What I mean is actually what Omnomnomnom said. :-) I'm confused about the the expression of this sentence, not the phrase "characteristic value".~ Anyway, I understand this sentence now, thank both of you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Vivian!